# OpenCV python запись в базу данных

Tags: python, opencv

python OpenCV через веб камеру считываю содержимое qr code, после необходимо вставлять эту запись
в базу данных, помогите пожалуйста как это реализовать, в питоне новенький..

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
import pymysql
from config import host, user, password, db_name

connection = pymysql.connect(
host=host,
port=3306,
user=user,
password=password,
database=db_name,
cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
success, frame = cap.read()

if not success:
    break

for code in decode(frame):
    decoded_data = code.data.decode("utf-8")
    rect_pts = code.rect

    if decoded_data:
        pts = np.array([code.polygon], np.int32)
        cv2.polylines(frame, [pts], True, (255, 0, 0), 3)
        cv2.putText(frame, str(decoded_data), (rect_pts[0], rect_pts[1]), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, (0, 255, 0), 2)

    # insert data
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        insert_query = "INSERT INTO `userrs`(name) VALUES (frame)"
        cursor.execute(insert_query)
        connection.commit()

cv2.imshow("camera", frame)
cv2.waitKey(1)
```

cap.release()